# Chaining multiple tasks in Luigi

Tags: python-3.x, luigi

I have one Luigi tasks that is set up to fetch different data based on the parameters passed to it and another one that is meant to take those files and send them to our datalake. My issue is that I'm not sure how to schedule multiple versions of the first task in sequence so that they can later be sent to the datalake. Here's my code:

```
class ListStep(luigi.Task):

    listId = luigi.IntParameter()
    startDate = luigi.Parameter(None)
    endDate = luigi.Parameter(None)
    logPath = luigi.Parameter(None)
    messagePath = luigi.Parameter(None)
    summaryPath = luigi.Parameter(None)
    contactPath = luigi.Parameter(None)
    logFile = luigi.BoolParameter(True)
    endpoint = luigi.Parameter()
    subscribed = luigi.BoolParameter(True)
    fileSuffix = luigi.Parameter(None)

    def output(self):
        today =  datetime.datetime.now()
        todayName = today.strftime("%m%d%y")
        pipelineNameLog = "./pipelinelog/pipelinelog_{}_{}_{}.csv".format(client.listId, self.endpoint, todayName)
        return luigi.LocalTarget(pipelineNameLog)

    def run(self):
        client = ListkWriter(client_id, client_secret, listId = self.listId, logPath = self.logPath, contactPath = self.contactPath, messagePath = self.messagePath, summaryPath = self.summaryPath)

        if self.endpoint == "message":
            filesList = client.getMessages(startDate = self.startDate, endDate = self.endDate, log = self.logFile, fileSuffix = self.fileSuffix)
        elif self.endpoint == "contacts":
            filesList = client.getContacts(startDate = self.startDate, endDate = self.endDate,  log = self.logFile, fileSuffix = self.fileSuffix, subscribed = self.subscribed)
        elif self.endpoint == "summary":
            filesList = client.getSummary(startDate = self.startDate, endDate = self.endDate, log = self.logFile, fileSuffix = self.fileSuffix)

        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            for val in filesList:
                outfile.write(",".join([val, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")]))
                outfile.write("\n")

class Transfer(luigi.Task):

    step = luigi.TaskParameter()
    uploadPath = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return self.step

    def output(self):
        today =  datetime.datetime.now()
        todayName = today.strftime("%m%d%y")
        pipelineNameLog = "./pipelinelog/pipelinelog_{}_{}_{}.csv".format(client.listId, self.step.endpoint, todayName)
        return luigi.LocalTarget(pipelineNameLog)

    def run(self):
        containerClient = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(storageCreds, 'datalake')
        with self.input().open('r') as infile:
            fileUpload = infile.readlines()

        for file in fileUpload:
            pathFile = file.split(",")[0]
            fileName = ntpath.basename(pathFile)
            uploadName = self.uploadPath + fileName
            with open(pathFile, 'rb') as f:
                containerClient.upload_blob(uploadName, f)

path = "/test/"

mMessage = ListStep(endpoint = "message", startDate = startDate, listId = listDict['m'], summaryPath = path, logPath = path, messagePath = path, contactPath = path)
gMessage = ListStep(endpoint = "message", startDate = startDate, listId = listDict['g'], summaryPath = path, logPath = path, messagePath = path, contactPath = path)
mSummary = ListStep(endpoint = "summary", startDate = startDate, listId = listDict['m'], summaryPath = path, logPath = path, messagePath = path, contactPath = path)
gSummary = ListStep(endpoint = "summary", startDate = startDate, listId = listDict['g'], summaryPath = path, logPath = path, messagePath = path, contactPath = path)

luigi.run([Transfer(step = mMessage, uploadPath = path), Transfer(step = gMessage, uploadPath = path),
           Transfer(step = mSummary, uploadPath = path), Transfer(step = gSummary, uploadPath = path)],
          local_scheduler = True)
```

What I want to achieve is that once the data is fetched using the ListStep task (with the specified parameters), they can be sent to the datalake using the Transfer task. After the first set of operations is carried out, I want it to move to the next set of objects. My aim is not to have this all run in parallel, but rather in sequence. When I execute this script, it seems that the scheduler is only counting 5 tasks and not 8. Furthermore it moves on to execute the mMessage task, then the gMessage task without executing the Transfer task. It later chrashes because of an FileExistError and outputs the following summary:

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 5 tasks of which:
* 2 ran successfully:
    - 2 ListrakStep(...)
* 2 failed:
    - 2 ListrakStep(...)
* 1 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 was not granted run permission by the scheduler:
        - 1 Transfer(step=ListrakStep, destination=datalake, uploadPath=test/)

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, unless you have tasks require other tasks, you cannot guarantee that tasks will be run in a certain order. You may have read about the priority system in the docs, but that only determines what gets assigned to workers, not when the workers will complete their tasks. One way to sequence a task is to use the task parameter and build up a sequence like this:

```py
class SequenceTask(luigi.Task):
    prev_task = luigi.TaskParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return self.prev_task
    ...

a = SequenceTask(...)
b = SequenceTask(prev_task=a, ...)
c = SequenceTask(prev_task=b, ...)
```

You actually do this in your `TransferTask` (though I think you should instead require a `ListStep` parameterized by `TransferTask`, but if it works, it works), so it should be easy for you to implement.

I do not believe that the scheduler only discovered 5 tasks. It looks like it *scheduled* 5, but then did not give permission to the first `Transfer` task to run.

Note: Your output to `ListStep` is incorrect and **will** cause you issues in the future. You need to calculate datetimes outside of the `output` function, otherwise when `output` is called a second time, the dates will be different, so the task will never be complete.